# Sums and differences of distinct factors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

Given $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\tau_{k}(n)$ denote the $k$th positive factor of $n$ in strictly increasing order.

For example, $\tau_{1}(6) = 1; \tau_{2}(6) = 2; \tau_{3}(6) = 3; \tau_{4}(6) = 6$.

**Question.** For what $n$ are there distinct $a, b, p, q$ such that:

1. $\tau_{a}(n) + \tau_{b}(n) = \tau_{p}(n) - \tau_{q}(n)$, and
2. $\tau_{a}(n)\tau_{b}(n) = n = \tau_{p}(n)\tau_{q}(n)$

For example, $n = 6$ works with $a = 2; b = 3; p = 4; q = 1$:

This is because $2 + 3 = 6 - 1$, and $2 \cdot 3 = 6 = 6 \cdot 1$.

Notes:

- $\tau_1(n)=1$ for all $n$
- If $a,b,p,q$ exist for $n$ then
  $a',b',p',q'$ exist for $n\cdot m^2$ for all $m
     \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a'=am; b'=bm; p'=pm; q'=qm$
- Computing a few by hand, the admissible $n$ seem to sync up
  with OEIS [A009112](https://oeis.org/A009112)

---

**More generally:** For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we can assign a value 
$$\hat{\tau}(n)=\text{min}[\tau_{a}(n) + \tau_{b}(n)] - [\tau_{p}(n) - \tau_{q}(n)]$$

for distinct $a, b, p, q$ subject to the constraint $\tau_{a}(n)\tau_{b}(n) = n = \tau_{p}(n)\tau_{q}(n)$, where $\hat{\tau}=0$ for all values that satisfy the constraints mentioned above.

Does calculating $\hat{\tau}(n)$ or looking at the sequence of $\hat{\tau}(n)$s tell us anything meaningful?

Comment: $n=3k(k+1)(k+2)$ gives infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @MatthewConroy, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: As another extension, do the values at which these sums/differences coincide create another interesting sequence that we can draw any conclusions from?

Comment: The more general sequence does not even exist for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As a simple example, any prime $\rho$ will not have four distinct factors, so the constraints cannot be satisfied as they are currently written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the indices of the factors in the strictly increasing order don't actually play any role, I'll use $A,B,P,Q$ to denote the actual factors instead of $\tau_a(n)$, $\tau_b(n)$, $\tau_p(n)$ and $\tau_q(n)$. The condition given can then be rewritten as $AB=PQ=n$ and $A+B=P-Q$.

Let's start by showing that all numbers from OEIS [A009112](https://oeis.org/A009112) admit such factorizations. The terms of the sequence are areas of Pythagorean triangles and it is [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) that all such triangles have sides expressible as
$$\begin{eqnarray}
k & \cdot & (u^2-v^2) \\
k & \cdot & (2uv) \\
k & \cdot & (u^2+v^2)
\end{eqnarray}$$ for some positive integers $k$ and $u>v$, with $\gcd(u,v)=1$. Now, consider
$$\begin{array}{cc}
A=k\cdot v\cdot (u+v) & P=k\cdot u\cdot (u+v) \\
B=k\cdot u\cdot (u-v) & Q=k\cdot v\cdot (u-v) \\
\end{array}$$
and see that these factors satisfy the given conditions and the products $AB$ and $PQ$ are both equal to the area of the corresponding triangle.

In the other direction, let $A,B,P,Q$ satisfying the conditions be given to us. Then, the integers $(A+Q)$, $(B+Q)$, and $(A+B)$ form a Pythagorean triple. Let's check it:

$$\begin{eqnarray}(A+Q)^2 + (B+Q)^2 & = & A^2 + B^2 + 2(A+B)Q + 2Q^2\\
& = & A^2 + B^2 + 2(P-Q)Q + 2Q^2 \\
& = & A^2 + B^2 + 2PQ \\
& = & A^2 + B^2 + 2AB \\
& = & (A+B)^2\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The area of this triangle is $$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}(A+Q)(B+Q) & = & \frac{1}{2}(AB + (A+B)Q + Q^2) \\
& = & \frac{1}{v2}(AB + (P-Q)Q + Q^2) \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}(AB + PQ) \\
& = & AB = PQ = n\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Thus, the numbers $n$ admitting two distinct factorizations satisfying the given conditions are exactly those in sequence A009112.